# Screenleap API integration with Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, screensharing

I am trying to integrate the "**Screenleap**" APIs into my Reactjs application.

I successfully called the endpoint with custom parameters and get the response.

As per screeleap documentation I passed this response object into `screenleap.startSharing()` function with other two parameters -  (`"presenterAppType": "NATIVE"` and `callbacks`).

Everytime when I pass all parameters it tries to download the desktop application which is already installed on my Mac.

It won't invoke the open Screenleap App prompt like as on the Screenleap website.

I am using ReactJS (with typeScript) and have included the below in my index.html.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.screenleap.com/js/screenleap.js">`

Does anyone encounter a similar situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.The app prompt works only with "**https**" links, so make sure you have **ngrok** link if you're testing on local.On production,if you have "**https**" it'll always work.